# Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Windows Forms .NET 5 (C#) y quiero hacer que todas las excepciones aparezcan en un MessageBox siempre

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excepciones, messagebox, .net-5

Tengo un formulario que a su vez abre otros formularios y que permite interactuar con una serie de ficheros. Claro está, puede haber infinidad de errores que surjan, pero yo no conozco. Por lo tanto, me gustaría filtrar todas las excepciones para que estas, se produzcan en el formulario o la clase que sea, siempre aparezcan en un MessageBox, ¿cómo puedo hacer esto?

He intentado hacer esto en el archivo Program.cs de mi aplicación:

```
             try
                {
                    Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new Principal());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    Application.Exit();
                }
```

Pero no me ha servido de nada. Me siguen saltando excepciones no controladas. ¿Hay alguna otra alternativa?

**Actualización 1:**

He intentado, según la respuesta de abajo lo siguiente:

Clase para manejar excepciones:

```
static class UtilidadesExcepciones
    {
        static public void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Se ha producido el siguiente error no controlado:\n\n" + e + 
                "\n\nPara evitar la pérdida de datos le recomendamos que " +
                "cierre la aplicación y vuelva a abrirla. En caso de que ya lo haya " +
                "intentado, consulte con el desarrollador. Pulse 'Aceptar' para cerrar la aplicación", "Error", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Línea en `Program.cs`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UtilidadesExcepciones.UnhandledException);

// Arriba también añado el using para que funcione al estar en diferente espacio de nombres
```

Comment: Pon el codigo q has intentado

Comment: Hola @Japv!! Es que en realidad no se cómo hacerlo, por eso no he publicado lo que he intentado, pues no encuentro nada. Tendría que rodear todo con `try catch`, pero me parece demasiado engorroso, y me gustaría saber si hay alguna alternativa más fácil, pues no la conozco.

Comment: O sea tu problema es que tendrias que poner muchos try/catch en muchos lugares del codigo?

Comment: Sí, me gustaría saber si hay forma de centralizar eso. Es decir, que pueda hacer que todas las excepciones no controladas (sin try catch) deriven a un método X y ese método realice una acción con ellas. Si habría otra forma de hacerlo, claro... Sino hago con `try catch` y ya está :)

Comment: Mira si hay una forma, pero tu sabes que el sitio tienes sus reglas y si te doy la respuesta, sin q tu hayas puesto codigo, alguien puede empezar a dar votos negativos o cerrar la pregunta, asi q pon algun codigo que tenga algun try/catch y dale una forma a tu pregunta para que pueda ser respondidad, no es culpa mia, el sitio funciona asi, te espero

Comment: Gracias @Japv!! Ya está

Comment: ok, ahora dame un tiempo

Comment: Perfecto, sin problema muchas gracias!!

Comment: Revisa y me dices

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123717/discussion-between-japv-and-cjimenecue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr eso que deseas puedes hacer uso del **manejador de eventos**:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

Este evento se invoca cuando se produce una **excepción no controlada** en nuestra aplicación, por lo tanto nos permite capturar dicha excepción y si lo deseas guardar información de la misma, sin que nuestra aplicación se "rompa", es decir teóricamente ocurre una excepción, la capturamos, mostramos un mensaje personalizado, guardamos una traza del error, y nuestra aplicación seguirá funcionando.

Para ello te propongo que crees una nueva clase, por ejemplo:

```
static class Excepciones
{
   static public void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {                
        MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido una excepción inesperada.\nContacte con el administrador de la aplicación.", "Excepción", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);        
    }
}
```

Para capturar el mensaje, o cualquier atributo de la excepción puedes hacer lo siguiente(yo no lo hago en el código que te pongo):

```
((Exception)e).Message//Quizá podrías mostrar un mensaje con esta información.
```

Lo que hacemos aquí es una clase que va a tener un método estático con la firma de los métodos que puede aceptar el **evento** **UnhandledException**, es decir un **parámetro de tipo** **object** y otro **parámetro de tipo** **UnhandledExceptionEventArgs**.

Una vez hecho esto vamos al **Program.cs** y ponemos lo siguiente:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Excepciones.UnhandledException);
Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware); //Este codigo es tuyo lo puse pq tu lo tenias puesto
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Principal());
```

La primera línea:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Excepciones.UnhandledException);
```

Nos va a poner en el evento que maneja las excepciones el método que previamente hicimos.

**Ojo**: si el **namespace** en donde declaras la **clase** **Excepciones** es diferente al del **fichero** **Program.cs**, deberías añadirlo mediante un **using**, es decir en el fichero **Program.cs** hipotéticamente pondrías:

```
using namespaceExcepciones;
```

**Ojo**: si ejecutas tu proyecto desde el Visual Studio se seguirán lanzando excepciones ya que estás en el entorno de desarrollo, para verificar que controlas las excepciones correctamente debes ejecutar el .exe de tu aplicación.

Otra forma de hacer lo de arriba sería usar el **manejador de eventos**
**Application.ThreadException**, incluso ambos pueden convivir, como todo tienen sus pro y contras, si lo deseas puedes investigar sus diferencias en internet.

Se trabaja practicamente igual que el manejador de eventos antes explicado.

Tu **clase** **Excepciones** quedaría así:

```
static class Excepciones
{
   static public void ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {            
        MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido una excepción inesperada.\nEspere unos segundos y vuelva a intentarlo.\nEn caso de persistir el error contacte con el administrador de la aplicación.\n\n*Causa más probable: fallo en la conexión a la base de datos.", "Excepción", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);                  
    }
}
```

Igualmente definimos un método que tenga la misma firma que el **manejador de eventos** **ThreadException**, es decir este método tendrá dos parámetros, uno de tipo **object** y otro de tipo **ThreadExceptionEventArgs**. Este método igualmente muestra un mensaje de que ha ocurrido una excepción.

Y en el **Program.cs** ponemos:

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Excepciones.ThreadException);
```

Es prácticamente igual al otro e incluso puedes usar los dos a la vez.

Comment: Hola @Japv!! Pues la verdad es que no me funciona, me siguen saltando las excepciones como "no controladas". Actualizo lo que he intentado en la pregunta, aunque creo que he hecho lo que me decías, pero por si acaso:

Comment: @cjimenecue, se me olvido decirte una cosa muy importante, si corres tu programa desde el visual studio se seguiran generando excepciones, ya que estas en el entorno de desarrollo. Las excepciones se controlan bien en tu .exe, por lo que prueba ahi, abriendo el ejecutable de tu aplicacion.

Comment: Si si, también he probado corriéndolo desde mi ".exe" y me falla.

Comment: @cjimenecue, pero el mensaje q tu creas se logra mostrar

Comment: No, me aparece el mensaje por defecto que me dice "excepción no controlada". Exactamente lo mismo que me aparecía antes de hacer nada.

Comment: @cjimenecue, modificado revisa